# How to query similar word in Hyperledger-composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How to query similar word in Hyperledger-composer? like LIKE in sql, how to sovle that. Thank you.

Comment: hi there - LIKE is not supported in the Composer Query language. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433254/how-to-query-to-include-specific-words-in-hyperledger-composer-query for more detailed explanation. The closest would be to use REST APIs (for which you need to stand up a REST server) and apply a 'LIKE' filter there - as described here  https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html - example filters are shown here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#filters

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the composer query, it is quite limited.

Basic query tutorial of composer is [Here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries)

Advanced example page is [Here](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/cl-create-powerful-blockchain-queries-with-hyperledger-composer/)

There is no function like "LIKE" as I know.